# Store method in Laravel Controller 5.5 on server does not work

Tags: laravel, controller

I have developed a CRUD application in laravel 5.5
All methods works fine in local laravel (I mean with the "simulator" started by command php artisa serve), but after the deploy of the application in xampp the method store in my controller stop to works(just this)!

In my web.php I added this route:

```
Route::resource('example','exampleControllerView');
```

the result of the command php artisan:

```
            POST     | example                           | example.store        | App\Http\Controllers\exampleControllerView@store    
|        | GET|HEAD  | example                           | example.index        | App\Http\Controllers\exampleControllerView@index  
|        | GET|HEAD  | example/create                    | example.create       | App\Http\Controllers\exampleControllerView@create 
|        | GET|HEAD  | example/{example}                     | example.show         | App\Http\Controllers\exampleControllerView@show  
|        | PUT|PATCH | example/{example}                     | example.update       | App\Http\Controllers\exampleControllerView@update 
|        | DELETE    | example/{example}                     | example.destroy      | App\Http\Controllers\exampleControllerView@destroy
|        | GET|HEAD  | example/{example}/edit                | example.edit         | App\Http\Controllers\exampleControllerView@edit
```

this is the method store in my controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
```

{

```
$request->validate([
  'name' => 'required|min:4',
  'description'=> 'required',
]);

$example = example::create(['name' => $request->name,'description' => $request->description]);
return redirect('/example/'.$example->id);
```

}

This is the view create (url : http://localhost/project/public/example/create):

```
    <form action="/example" method="post">
{{ csrf_field() }}
 <div class="form-group">
   <label for="title">example nome</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="taskTitle"  name="name">
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
   <label for="description">example descrizione</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleDescription" name="description">
 </div>
 @if ($errors->any())
   <div class="alert alert-danger">
       <ul>
           @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
               <li>{{ $error }}</li>
           @endforeach
       </ul>
   </div>
 @endif
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

After the submit button I see in the new page this uri:

```
http://localhost/example
```

and in the page a 404 error: Object not found!
The requested URL does not exist on this server.

I thing that is a problem of routing and url but I don not the why in local all work fine...

thanks in advances

Comment: Please show the `show` controller method.

Comment: You can see above, anyway:

Comment: public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
      'name' => 'required|min:4',
      'description'=> 'required',
    ]);
    $example = example::create(['name' => $request->name,'description' => $request->description]);
    return redirect('/example/'.$example->id);

}

Comment: `show`, not `store`

Comment: public function show(example $example)
{
    return view('example.show',compact('example',$example));
}

Answer (score 0):

Change this line-

```
 <form action="/example" method="post">
```

To this-

```
 <form action="/project/public/example" method="post">
```

Better use [Laravel Collective](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.4/html), this will automatically configure your base path and has a lot of other benefits like `csrf protection`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work fine. It redirects a user to the `show` method with ID of created entity. Instead of using model binding, try to do this:

```
public function show($id)
{
    dd('The show method was executed and ID is ' . $id);
    ....
}
```